# How to avoid flicker when redrawing svg?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a couple of End points for eg: rule1, rule2. I need to switch between these two end points using button click event and display the data using d3js charts. When I'm switching between these two, I noticed a flicker which is uncomfortable to the eye. For every button click event I'm emptying the content in the respective divs using `$("id").html("")` . After the above command, I'm calling the functions which redraws the entire chart. I don't understand why there is a flicker on the screen.

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
   $("#stackhorizon").html(''); //chart-1
   $("#horizontalbar").html(''); //chart-2
   $("#atom").html(''); //chart-3
   var id = $(this).attr('id'); // id holds the url
   url = id;
   drawDashBoard(url);
});
```

drawDashBoard re-draws all the charts. Sometimes there's flicker and sometimes there is smooth transition.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the new chart off-screen and then directly replace with the results?

Comment: Is `drawDashBoard` your own custom function? Doesn't D3 have a built-in one you could use?

Comment: @Sirko I think I'm doing that. The chart functions are called after emptying the content and the svgs are being appended to the empty divs after drawing is done.

Comment: @Waxi yes it is. I had to write some functionality which changes the data and the changed data is fed to normal d3 pie  , stack layouts.

Comment: @SharathV Not quite. I would try to draw the charts first in a div, that is not visible to the user. Once it is complete (which might take a few ms) replace the contents of the old container with that new chart. I guess your flickering results from loading the new data or an extensive drawing procedure.

Comment: @Sirko I made it work the other way. The emptying of previous chart should be done right before the new svg drawing which is inside the function call. I'm not sure if this is a proper way of redrawing the dashboard from a new end point.
Eg:  `function chart(data){
                          $("horizontalbar").html("");`
                           `// Draw the svg with new data;`
                     `}`

Comment: @Sirko Forgot to add, after drawing, like you said just add the new content to the div. eg. `$("horizontalbar").html(chart(data));`  You can post it as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that flickering is probably either the delay until new data has been loaded or your chart creation takes a considerable time.

In both cases it would be beneficial to leave the old chart visible as long as possible before replacing it with the new one.

So option one would be: Draw the chart in a separate `<div>` element that is not visible to the user. Once you're finished drawing replace the old chart with the new one.

The other option would be to wait with deleting at least until the data is available. So in your `drawDashBoard()` you will at some point have something like `d3.json()`. Put the removal of the old chart in the callback of that data-retrieving call.

Comment: "The other option would be to wait with deleting at least until the data is available. So in your drawDashBoard() you will at some point have something like d3.json(). Put the removal of the old chart in the callback of that data-retrieving call". Yes, I think this is what I was doing. I have the new data and then calling the function. Thank you.